# Spring Cloud Stream determine topic Kafka message came from

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

My **@StreamListener** listening for multiple Kafka topics(totally like 10 topics) specified in **spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination** property.

Is there any way to determine the topic message came from inside the **@StreamListener** annotated method? I wouldn't like to configure bindings for all topics separately and write 10 almost identical StreamListeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `KafkaHeaders. RECEIVED_TOPIC` you can specify a separate parameter on the `@StreamListener` method. Something like this in Spring Kafka docs:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "qux", topicPattern = "myTopic1")
public void listen(@Payload String foo,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) Integer key,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts
        ) {
    ...
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-listener-annotation

Comment: That's what I looked for